# .NET Framework - Installing the application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, deployment-project

I want to make an application (windows application) using C# and .NET Framework 3.5.

I want to make the install the application. I want the installation to determine - whether the user has the framework in the system. If the user does not have a framework - I want to install it.

How to create an installation of application with NET Framework 3.5?

Comment: ok, good luck. and what is your question?

Comment: Yeah. No question here. Voting to close. Jenan - please read up basic english. The part that questions contain one sentence asking something and ending with a "?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use something like [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to install your application this will happen automatically. When you set it up it determines which version of .NET is required for your application. It doesn't include the required version in the installer - so your installer says the same size regardless - but puts in code that will install the correct version from Microsoft as required.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [Windows Installer XML toolkit](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), which contains ways to determine whether the required .NET version is installed. Also, you get an MSI installer.

Another way would be to use [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). You can write code using the integrated Pascal script interpreter which checks for the installed framework version.

The Installer project type that comes with "higher" versions of Visual Studio also contains ways to make the .NET Framework a requirement.

I've worked with all three of them and can tell you: it works. There may be other ways, like [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), but I haven't used them.